# How to retrieve Azure AD user information in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, .net-core-3.1

I have an app that is hosted in Azure and is behind our organizations Azure AD. I have to be authenticated with the AD to access the site. The .NET Core app itself is set to use Anonymous Authentication. My question is how can I access the Azure AD user claims so I can display their name in the UI, use their SID to save user specific UI states, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MS Graph to get information  of users. The document which can help you is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

The C# snippet which can help you is below:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Please let me know if you need any more help.